# How to get the label id for a label template in Word

Tags: vb.net, ms-word

I have an application that prints labels based on Word templates.  The templates need a label id.  I can find it by recording a macro and looking at the contents.

```
Application.MailingLabel.DefaultPrintBarCode = False
Application.MailingLabel.PrintOutByID LabelID:="1359805383", Address:="", _
    ExtractAddress:=False, LaserTray:=wdPrinterManualFeed, SingleLabel:=False _
    , PrintEPostageLabel:=False, Vertical:=False
```

Here the label id is **1359805383** and I can use it like this:

```
    ML.CreateNewDocumentByID(LabelID:="1359805383", Address:="", AutoText:="ToolsCreateLabels1",
                             LaserTray:=WdPaperTray.wdPrinterManualFeed, ExtractAddress:=False,
                             PrintEPostageLabel:=False, Vertical:=False)
```

But what I would like to do is allow the users to use other labels.
Allow then to enter "Avery 5160" and for me to get the appropriate labelid to pass to word.  I can't find anything on this.

Comment: Are you sure you are coding in vb.net (using Visual Studio)? The code created by "Record a Macro" is VBA. If you are coding in VBA, you should edit your question to replace the vb.net tag with the word-vba tag.

Comment: @Blackwood - You can not use VB.NET to record a macro.  Macro recordings only work with VBA so any code the result of a macro recorder will ALWAYS be VBA.  That should be expected (hint, no surprise).  Recording a macro in VBA is a good starting point to get .Net code.  And yes I am sure I am coding in VB.NET.  You can not make a stand alone application, like the one I'm writing, with VBA.  Also if I was using VBA I could display the labels dialog and let the user select thier labels and get the label id that way.  That would be quite kludgy in a stand alone app.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It didn't seem obvious to me from the question that you were aware of the difference (possibly my fault).